# Maven repository for WSO2-IS service stubs?

Tags: maven, soap, wso2, stubs, wso2-identity-server

In what Maven repository can I find the various (SOAP) service stubs that ship with WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0?

The stubs themselves ship with WSO2 Identity Server, in the directory `/repository/components/plugins/`. The OAuth stubs for example are provided in `/repository/components/plugins/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub_5.0.7.jar`

The jar file contains a pom file, which identifies the library with Maven coordinates. For the example above, these coordinates are

```
<groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity</groupId>
<artifactId>carbon-service-stubs</artifactId>
<version>5.0.7</version>
```

I'd love to use the Maven artifacts from a public repository, but so far, I've only found very outdated artifacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are available publicly in wso2 maven repo.
for e.g if you want org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.stub you can get it from http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/wso2/carbon/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.stub/5.0.7/

You can find all stubs here
http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases

Comment: Ah, right you are! I was looking at the wrong path within that repository. For future reference: do not use http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/wso2/carbon/org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.stub/ but instead use http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/wso2/carbon/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.stub/